# Best way to protect a REST service that will be accessed by mobile and desktop applications

Tags: wcf, rest, mobile-phones, security

I have REST services that I was planning on protecting with Windows Integrated Authentication (NTLM), as it should only be accessible to those internal to the company, and it will end up being on a website that is accessible by the public.

But, then I thought about mobile applications and I realized that Android, for example, won't be able to pass the credentials needed, so now I am stuck on how to protect it.

This is written in WCF 4.0, and my thought was to get the credentials, then determine who the user is and then check if they can use the GET request and see the data.

I don't want to force the user to pass passwords, as this will then be in the IIS log, and so is a security hole.

My present concern is for the GET request, as POST will be handled by the same method I expect.

One solution, which I don't think is a good option, would be to have them log into Sharepoint, then accept only forwarded reqests from Sharepoint.

Another approach would be to put my SSO solution in front of these services, which would then force people to log in if they don't have credentials, so the authentication would be done by SSO, and since the web service directory could be a subdirectory of the main SSO page, then I could decrypt the cookie and get the username that way, but, that would be annoying for the mobile users, which would include the senior management.

So, what is a way to secure a REST service so that it is known whom is making the request so that authorization decisions can be made, and will work for iphones, android and blackberry smartphones.

Comment: By asking this question on here, is it possible for people to trace you and find out your project? Just be careful what you share on the internet. Good luck - I cannot help though.

Comment: Ok you're James Black and your profile leads me to your linked in page which tells me where you work. That's a lot of info to tie together with this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem so let me give you the details and would also appreciate feedback. Since you are using an internal system you have one extra option that I have listed.

My first option isn't perfect, yes it could be hacked but still - better than nothing. With each request you pass the device's unique identifier along with a hash. You generate the hash using a salt embedded in the application along with the id. On the server you match the incoming hash with one you generate at the server, with the passed unique identifier. If someone "roots" their device, and is smart enough they could find the salt - you can obscure it further but ultimately it could be stolen. Also, I keep all requests on SSL to just help hide the process. My "enhancement" to this process is to pass back new salts after each request. New devices get 1 chance to obtain the next salt or get locked out ... not sure about that step yet.

Now another approach, is to have the user enter a "salt" or username and password only an internal user would know - the device obtains a token and then passes it (on SSL) with each request. Nobody outside your company could obtain that so this is probably best. I can't use this since my app is in the app store.

Hope that helps! Let us all know if you ever found a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, in order to protect data in the system, is to force people to first log in to the application that the REST services support (our learning management system), as I have written an SSO solution that will write out a cookie with encrypted data.

Then, the REST service will look for that cookie, which disappears when you close the browser, and I don't care if the cookie is expired, I just need the username from it, then I can look in a config file to see if that user is allowed to use that REST service.

This isn't ideal, and what I want to do is redirect through the SSO code, and have it then send the person back to the REST service, but that is not as simple as I hoped.

My SSO code has lots of redirects, and will redirect someone to a spot they pick in the learning management system, I just need to get it to work with the other application.